# javascript pushState on a subdomain throws exception

Tags: javascript

In my js file:

```
window.history.pushState('','',slug);
```

I know about security restrictions for the pushState method:

> The new URL must be of the same origin as the current URL; otherwise,
>   pushState() will throw an exception.

However, in my website I use a domain: `www.mydomain.com` where pushState works fine. But when I call the method on my subdomain `subdomain.mydomain.com`, it throws a weird exception:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': A
>   history state object with URL 'http://0.0.7.210/' cannot be created in
>   a document with origin 'http://subdomain.mydomain.com'.

I do call the IP 0.0.7.210 as something internal but I get this exception on development + live environment.

I do resolve my subdomains via Route53 by the way. Maybe it has to do with that?

Comment: With what arguments are you calling the method? It seems you are using a different domain in the first argument (that IP) than the domain on which you are.

Comment: the pushState snipped is embedded in a function but there I only pass some content relevant arguments, nothing important.

Comment: The url that you pass *is* important, as it apparently causes the error. Do you understand what the error message means?

Comment: I pass an url-slug as I want to manipulate the URL onclick. E.g user clicks on an image, the image loads via ajax and the URL changes to ``mydomain.com/this-image``- ``slug`` in this case was "this-image". Understandable?

Comment: The error indicates that you are passing `http://0.0.7.210/this-image` instead. Can you `console.log` the `slug` to make sure?

Comment: I think I found the issue. I passed an additional ``/`` which caused the error.

Comment: You might want to [post an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) then :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that pushing an additional `/`solved the issue.

Changed this

```
window.history.pushState('','',slug);
```

to this

```
window.history.pushState('','','/'+slug);
```